# Dijkstra's Algorithm pseudocode "U" symbol

Tags: pseudocode, dijkstra

I'm currently trying to follow pseudocode for Dijkstra's Algorithm, but I'm having difficulty understand what one of the lines means.

```
DijkstrasAlgorithm(G, w, s)
    InitalizeSingleSource(G, s)
    S = 0
    Q = G.V
    while Q != 0
        u = ExtractMin(Q)
        S = S∪{u}
        for each vertex v ∈ G.Adj[u]
            Relax(u, v, w)
```

This part right here "S = S∪{u}" is what's confusing me. I'm not sure what S is supposed to be equal to. Could someone explain? Thanks!

Comment: Thats a union operator from set theory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That’s the [set union](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(set_theory)) operator. S here is the set of all nodes for which the shortest path has been computed, and this line means “add the node u to that set.”

Mechanically, S ∪ {u} is the set consisting of everything already in S, plus the node u. That’s why S = S ∪ {u} means to add u to S.

(As a note, I think the pseudocode has a typo in where S was declared. You probably meant to initialize it to the empty set ∅ rather than the number 0.)

Dijkstra’s algorithm is a pretty tough one to understand purely from pseudocode. I recommend checking out a tutorial somewhere so that you have a high-level intuition for what’s going on. It’s much easier to understand this pseudocode by mapping the contents onto your conceptual understanding.